# Bulk delete support in Cosmos DB using .NET SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Based on documentation related to the cosmos db bulk executer(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net), there is support for a bulk delete via the bulk executer.

However, the examples under the new bulk support within the .NET SDK (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/) does not explicitly state anything about deletion

I wanted to understand if there were any drawbacks to attempting a delete on several documents using the new bulk execution support (here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/), or if it is okay to proceed with using a similar pattern as the "Create" flow described in the sample.

Answer (score 2):

When Bulk mode is enabled, any point operation (ReadItem, CreateItem, UpsertItem, DeleteItem, ReplaceItem) will benefit from it, just follow the same pattern of the concurrent Tasks but instead of CreateItem, DeleteItem (or you could even mix different operation types).